# Error install mediapipe windows 11 with python 3.12

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, mediapipe

Message:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe==0.10.11 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe==0.10.11

Python 3.12
Visual code

[image]

Install package:
https://github.com/empowerdata/hands-tracking
But! Not found install mediapip!

Comment: Try this `py -m pip install opencv-python mediapipe msvc-runtime`